# Can't use select after include in repository pattern ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET Core and I'm trying to get just the username from user by using select, but I can't.

Maybe this question is bad but I just started a few days ago. If you can help please go ahead and thanks in advance

the error is here:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllOrders()
    {            
            var orders = await _unitOfWork.Orders.GetAll(o => o.IsReady == false,
                orderBy: item => item.OrderBy(x => x.OrderDate),
                include:i=>i.Include(x=>x.User).Select(x=>x.User.UserName));
            var results = _mapper.Map<IList<OrderDTO>>(orders);
            return Ok(results);                        
    }
```

the function in the generic repository:

```
public async Task<IList<T>> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>> include = null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = _db;

            if (expression != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(expression);
            }

            if (include != null)
            {
                query = include(query);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = orderBy(query);
            }
            return await query.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        }
```

[the error is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thn5v.png)

[the function in the generic repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/895a6.png)

Comment: It looks like you're missing an import System.Linq ?

Comment: @Doug 
unfortunately I've Imported it. that's not the reason

Comment: Can you please post actual code instead of images?

Comment: @PeterBons 
Done

Comment: @redwards510
I guess You can help me!

Comment: I suppose you are using EF? You should try to avoid having to  use Include statements. Your mapper should map the EF object to whatever projection you want. EF will take care of selecting only those fields from the DB that are needed.

Comment: In your case the means that projection should be done before the call to ToList in GetAll or GetAll should return an iqueryable that allows projection further up in the chain. Having to use includes means your logic is wrong.

Comment: @PeterBons
if I did it by using the mapper this will work. But in this case I fetch a lot of data from database I don't need them.

Comment: @PeterBons
I need to add projection after the include. Do you have an idea to do that?

Comment: Thanks for updating the question, can you also include any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not have that Select statement because it makes the Include syntax invalid. You should be able to access the UserName like this:

```
foreach(var order in orders)
{
    var userName = order.User.UserName;
}
```

Comment: I can map it and take only the username (in mapping)
but in this case I fetch data I don't need them.